# Identify obscure sci-fi indie short - Man has to convince cyborg gf that he loves her in the past to stop a robot vs human war in the present

Tags: story-identification, robots, love

It's pretty much all in the title. I did a bit of googling, no luck.

It's live-action with extensive CGI for the robots. It starts out with soldiers screaming and firing machine guns at dog-like robots climbing up a tower, then it zooms back to what they're defending:

A time machine.
 Or holodeck, what have you.

They have rigged one of the enormous robots up to some kind of program to re-write (I would assume) the collective memory of the robots. A man stands on a bridge, and states he's ready to try again. The program/time machine engages, and the dog-robot is transformed into a girl with cybernetic implants.

It becomes clear that they broke up years ago, and that somehow caused the war. If he can convince her that he doesn't want to break up after all, the war will end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That would be [Tears of Steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tears_of_Steel).

Grabbing from the [IMDB Plot summary](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2285752/):

> Thom just wanted to be an astronaut. His girlfriend Celia just wanted to create robots - and for him to not be freaked out by her cyborg hand. How was Thom supposed to know that breaking up with her would make her take out her anger on the rest of humanity using her robots? It seems the only possible way of undoing everything...is to overwrite her memory of what happened 40 years ago.

I believe it's legitimately able to be watched on Youtube, here: [Tears of Steel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6MlUcmOul8)